# Need to print number of elements, total and average for random number array java

Tags: java

```
package genrandom;

import java.util.Random;

public class GenRandom {
    
       static int maxNumber = 0;

public static int GenRandom() {
    return new Random().nextInt(899)+100;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int randomNumber = GenRandom();
        if (randomNumber > maxNumber) {
            maxNumber = randomNumber;
        }
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
    }
    System.out.println("The greatest file size is: " + maxNumber + "MB");
} // TODO code application logic here
    }
```

I am able to print the greatest number however need to print how many elements there are, the total and the average

Comment: What hinders you to do that? Any problems you are facing with your attempts?

Answer (score 3):

For reference, this can be solved easily by using streams (Java 8):

```
var stats = IntStream.generate(GenRandom::GenRandom)
    .limit(10)
    .summaryStatistics();
```

and then `stats.getMax()`, `stats.getSum()` and `stats.getAverage()`. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) for more details.

It is also efficient as all of them are computed in one go instead of multiple iterations. And you even get multithreading for free by just calling `parallel()`, in case you have thousands of numbers to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

This calculates the average and total by keeping track of each in the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbers = 0; // How many random numbers have been generated
    double total = 0; // Total of all random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int randomNumber = GenRandom();
        if (randomNumber > maxNumber) {
            maxNumber = randomNumber;
        }
        numbers++; // Add 1 to count of random numbers generated
        total += randomNumber; // Add number to total
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
    }
    System.out.println("The greatest file size is: " + maxNumber + "MB");
    System.out.println("There were " + total + " total numbers");
    // Average is the total divided by the amount of numbers
    System.out.println("The average file size was: " + (total/numbers) + " MB");
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think for a beginner, this is much better than using streams. +1